# How does HFI (high frequency injection) work with BLDC motors

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, vector-control, sinusoidal

How does HFI work with BLDC motors.
In this video: [VESC HFI: Sensorless position tracking at zero speed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qV1_xyrgzs) he explains how HFI works, however i don't get how it can work with motors that have trapezoid back-EMF such as the one he is using.

The code belongs to the author of the VESC project which is an open source firmware implementing FOC with HFI. I tried understanding the code, however i couldn't given the level of complexity.

Can someone explain how HFI is implemented and how it works with trapezoid back-EMF BLDC motors?

[VESC github repo](https://github.com/vedderb/bldc)

Comment: Did you try looking for other resources that actually try explaining what high frequency injection is?

Comment: Cant find any trustworthy resources, if you can provide suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I skimmed through Google materials and there are two steps.

1. First it measures the impedance of the coils by sending in current at a particular D-Q angle (I think). Then it changes the angle and compares the two impedances. In other words, it's measuring inductance or the strength of the two flux paths through the motor. This lets you get the rotor position, more or less.

[image]
[image]
https://www.controleng.com/articles/understanding-permanent-magnet-motors/

2. But you can see from the graph above that it is symmetrical so there is an ambiguity which needs to be resolved. Unless perfectly centered, the
   presence of the PM field will bias the ferromagnetic domains in the
   iron core so it saturates in one direction earlier than the other. You can ramp up current in both directions and measure when it saturates to differentiate whether you are near a N or S pole. I'm not sure quite sure when this is done though.

Pretty cool. I'll have to read up on it more tommorrow.

Comment: regarding the ambiguity, isn't this resolved by using all 3 phases?

Comment: @EmbeddedSoftwareEngineer I never looked into it further so honestly I couldn't tell you. But my theory is that, assuming your approach works, it seems it would only work at zero speed. I think the intended usage for this method is not rotor sensing at startup but at low speed where you don't want to be de-energizing the phases involved with the rotation to energize phases not involved with the rotation.

Comment: I am under the impression that this HFI is done on top of the regular motor phase currents, not standalone.